# Writing from a combobox to a list(Update)

Tags: vba, combobox

Ok.....I think I have developed a solid enough understanding of the language to progress with this. This Update is a completly revised version of my code and I will detail this as specific as I can.

Program objectives:
1.) Create Userform that allows user to log data.(Working)
2.) Allow combo boxes to write to a lists that acts as database.(I have one dynamic range set called 3.) 3.) ulMech which is created using the name manager and is complet with the offset and the list expands)
4.) The userform is a multi tab userform that will contain a tab specific to each list.
5.) all data is populated to specific set of cells on sheet 1(working).

New error object required for  when I click to add my reason.

I also added in the column to reference entry numbers so that I can work with the loop that has been submitted previous to this edit.

My Code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub cmAdd_Click()

Add_Reason
Update_Combo

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyCell As Long
Dim cellD As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate


'Determine Empty Cell
emptyCell = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("L:L")) + 1

'Determine empty cell date
cellDate = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("K:K")) + 1


If CheckBoxM.Value = True Then Cells(emptyCell, 12).Value = CheckBoxM.Caption

If CheckBoxS.Value = True Then Cells(emptyCell, 12).Value = Cells(emptyCell, 12).Value & " " & CheckBoxS.Caption

If CheckBoxE.Value = True Then Cells(emptyCell, 12).Value = Cells(emptyCell, 12).Value & " " & CheckBoxE.Caption

'Transfer Data tO Sheet.
Cells(cellDate, 11).Value = TextBoxULD.Value

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButtonP1S_Click()

Begin

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate


'Determine Empty Row
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer Information To Next available Row.
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBoxDate.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBoxWeek.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBoxBN.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBoxBT.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBoxST.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = TextBoxTD.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = TextBoxY.Value

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonT1C_Click()

UserForm.Hide

End Sub



Private Sub Frame2_Click()

Frame2.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

End Sub

'Filling the ComboBox
Public ws As Worksheet
Const wsName As String = "ulMech"

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dbSheet)
Update_Combo

Sub Begin()

'Do Things
 MsgBox frmMain.CmBox1.ListCount & ""

End Sub
Sub Add_Reason()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim s As String

    s = frmMain.CmBox1 'Error occurs here object required

    With ws
        Do

            r = r + 1
        Loop Until .Cells(r, 1) = ""
        .Cells(r, 1) = r + 1
        .Cells(r, 2) = s
    End With
End Sub

Sub Delete_Reason()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim s As String

    s = frmMain.CmBox1 

    With ws
        Do

            r = r + 1
            Loop Until .Cells(r, 2) = s
            .Rows(r).Delete
            End With
    End With
End Sub
Sub Update_Combo()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Integer

    frmMain.CmBox1.Clear

    With ws
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(r, 1)) Then
            .Cells(r, 1) = r
            frmMain.CmBox1.AddItem .Cells(r, 2)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Set Empty Text Box Values

TextBoxDate.Value = ""
TextBoxBN.Value = ""
TextBoxBT.Value = ""
TextBoxST.Value = ""
TextBoxTD.Value = ""
TextBoxY.Value = ""
TextBoxULD.Value = ""

'Set checkbox values to false
CheckBoxM.Value = False
CheckBoxS.Value = False
CheckBoxE.Value = False

End Sub
```

Heres my database, Im working on printing to ul mechanical which has the list name ulMech. Once I get this going it will be just a case of changing the ranges and duplicating the code.

The submit button deals with printing the data to sheet one which works for the checkboxes and date etc. I havnt printed the combobox code yet becasue i want to get the db update working and then ill be able to tidy up.

The add reason button is there to add the reason to the list. I will be adding a close button to. Ill run the delete code at a later date.

Each tab is dedicated to a particular type of data  so that the program is clear and easy to use. The program they were using was not clear or easy to use so Ive been asked to make it simple.

Here is sheet1 (data will be printing to each cell so that stats reports can be generated along with graphs. This isnt imprtant as it works....for now....

Here is the Sheet that will be updating the combo boxes ulMech is the one we are concerned with. The sheet is called dbSheets.

I hope this is clear, Im pretty close to solving it Im just only at the lanuage about a week so Im still getting to grips with it.I hope this is clear and concise. Thank you for your time. I cant post the Images because I need ten or more rep points =(

Comment: It looks like `findblank` is initialized but starts at 0. Is that maybe part of the problem?
I don't think `...Cells(0, 1)` is legal.

Comment: Also, I think there may be a typo after your code block. I'm not sure what type of error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your findblank variable worth 0 when the routine enter the first loop, which cause the program to send an exception. Set it to 1 first.

Probably you meant by findblank = findblank = 1 >> findblank = findblank + 1

But i'm not sure finding blank spot will enabled you to update the combobox.item in the sheet.

I suggest you to erase all comment and then rewrite all items in combobox.

```
Private Sub ComboBoxUL_Change()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Range(<initial range for list>)
rng.CurrentRegion.ClearContents

Dim RowCount As Integer
RowCount = ComboBoxUL.ListCount

For x = 1 To RowCount
 rng.Cells(x, 1) = ComboBoxUL.List(0, x - 1)
Next x



End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The error im getting is is saying list seperator, or so Im pretty sure its a compile error which would make sense considering the findblank is starting at 0 which is invalid when referencing cell A1. Im going to try this code that you posted and see if I have better luck. The most important thing is that it updates a new reason to my list in sheet 2 because I need to update like 20 different lists due to the fact that a lot can go wrong on a chemical plant. Ill get back soon with a progress report.

Answer (score 0):

Dedicate a worksheet to contain the list contents. 2 columns. Column 1 is the Number of the entry, Column 2 is the "Reason".

```
    Column
    A     B       
Row ---   ---
1   1     Reason1 ' Instead of having the first entry here you could use this row for headers
2   2     Reason2
3   3     Reason3
4   4     Reason4
5   5     Reason5
```

[image: List Sheet]

1 CommandButton to "Add" & 1 to "Delete"
Maybe a standard "Submit" & "Close" as well.
[image: form with all the tools]

1. Write code for "Add" procedure which takes the current value of the
   combobox and puts it at the bottom of the list on the "CBoxList"
   worksheet.
2. Write code for "Delete" procedure which takes the current value of the combobox and finds it in     the "CBoxList" worksheet and deletes
   that row.
3. Write code for "Update CBox" procedure which runs when initializing the form, when adding a value and when deleting a
   value. This procedure will clear the forms combobox and re-add all of
   the items on the "CBoxList" worksheet to the combobox.

### This is what the code within the form will look like:

```
Public ws As Worksheet              ' This will be referenced within the form subs and functions
Const wsName As String = "CBoxList" 

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName) ' Initialize variable
    Update_Combo
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Begin                                ' Main Procedure
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me                            
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Add_Reason                           
    Update_Combo
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Delete_Reason
    Update_Combo
End Sub

Sub Begin()
    ' Do_Things
    MsgBox frmMain.cmbReason.ListCount & " Reasons."
End Sub

Sub Add_Reason()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim s As String

    s = frmMain.cmbReason

    With ws
        Do
            r = r + 1
        Loop Until .Cells(r, 1) = ""
        .Cells(r, 1) = r ' If the worksheet list has a header then use: ' .Cells(r,1) = r + 1 
        .Cells(r, 2) = s
    End With
End Sub

Sub Delete_Reason()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim s As String

    s = frmMain.cmbReason

    With ws
        Do
            r = r + 1
        Loop Until .Cells(r, 2) = s
        .Rows(r).Delete
    End With
End Sub

Sub Update_Combo()
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer

    frmMain.cmbReason.Clear

    With ws
        For r = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(r, 1)) Then
                .Cells(r, 1) = r                        'Reset ID instance
                frmMain.cmbReason.AddItem .Cells(r, 2)
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This has been most helpful, Since Writing this Ive been on a vb tutorial binge. As a result I started the program again and put in a multitab userform. Im currently back to writing to the list which is on my second sheet, so I will look over this code and if I fully understand it then I should be able to integrate it into the new program. Your answer is fantastic, very well structured. I will get to this thread later this evening and hopefully I will be able to share significant progress. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Im getting a object error for s = frm.Main.CmBox1 fpr the Add_Reason() function. Ive Dim s as String so it is declared and I would Assume specified?

Comment: I think frmMain needs to be defined but I cant figure out how

Comment: I think frmMain needs to be defined but I cant figure out how, all the information I can find on this seems to refer to MS access whereas im using excell instead of access so im not sure if it holds true in vba. Also is your frmMain a class or variable because it doesnt seem to exist in the main form or sub form information.

Comment: When I put 

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName) ' Initialize variable
    Update_Combo

It crashes when I try to show my form. Im guessing this has to be in the initialise sub. Im using userform1.Show to open my form. I cant look at the loop for adding the reason until i solve this issue. The loop for adding the reason crashes at frmMain. I dont really understand how that works. s = frmMain.cmbReason is where the looping crashes. A little bit lost at the moment.